# ASP.NET Multiform Validation

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation, submit

I have 2 forms in my ASP.NET web form, and each of them needs validation.

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="">

    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb1" ValidationGroup="g1"/>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb1"
      ValidationGroup="g1" Display="Dynamic">
        field1 empty!!!
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit1" ValidationGroup="g1"/>

</form>

 <form id="form2" method="POST" action="">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tb2" ValidationGroup="g2"/>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb2"
    ValidationGroup="g2" Display="Dynamic">
        field2 empty!!!
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit2" ValidationGroup="g2"/></form>
```

The point is that when I submit the first form, everything's fine, but when I submit the second one with empty fields, the validation error messages are displayed, but the page is still submitted.
I tried to nest these forms and it worked, the validation was done correctly.
But I think that conceptually it's a bad solution.

Could you please suggest anything else?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one form in an ASP.NET "WebForm":
[One (ASP.Net) Form, To Rule Them All](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.421651.10)

Get rid of the extra form tags and just use the `ValidationGroups`.

Comment: But I can have only 1 form with runat="server" attribute.
Can't I have nested  forms there?